# Securely Connecting to SQL Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394108.aspx),

> All communications between Microsoft Azure SQL Database and your
>   application require encryption (SSL) at all times.

If this is the case, what is the difference between using the standard connection string of:

```
server.database.windows.net
```

and requiring security and using the "Secure Connection String" of:

```
server.database.secure.windows.net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted talks about validating the SSL Certificates used to make the Sql Connection to validate that a "man in the middle" attack cannot get your Sql UserName/Password.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack

It is your application that needs to validate the SSL Certificate to validate it is coming from SqlAzure. I don't see how changing the hostname and not requiring security will keep you safe.

Comment: The changed hostname is the hostname, provided by Azure, you have to connect to if you choose the option in SQL Azure to require a secure connection.

Comment: What is important to understand is that the code making the SqlConnection is responsible for validating the SSL Certificate.  Using a standard connection string I believe turns off that validation and will make you susceptible to man in the middle attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The information provided on the accepted answer is incorrect. The secure.database.windows.net connects to a security proxy in the region. It was intended for use with Sql Auditing and clients TDS 7.0. However, at this time SQL AUditing no longer uses that domain. That domain was documented previously on Microsoft Docs but as SQL Auditing was no longer using it, then that part of the documentation was removed.

You can safely connect to server.database.windows.net and be protected of man-in-the-middle attack.